# python, subprocess, ошибка сегментации

Tags: python, subprocess

Я хочу запустить mp3 файл в subprocess:

```
def play():
    subprocess.call(["ffplay", "-nodisp", "-autoexit", audio_file])
    return
```

Однако, когда я вызываю эту функцию, мне возвращается: Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск). Работаю в linux-mint 20.

Пробовал через другие библиотеки (pysound,pygame(почему то не хочет устанавливаться), pyaudio), но тоже кисло...

У кого-то есть идеи?

Comment: Похоже, у вас какая-то системная ошибка, не связанная с Python. Работает ли проигрыватель из FFmpeg, если запускать его напрямую, а не через Python?

Comment: да, при вводе в терминале команды ffplay voice.mp3 -autoexit, никаких ошибок нет